# Map configuration for kafka producer in properties file fails

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-kafka

I'm trying to add a producer configuration to my project, using Spring Integration and Kafka underneath.

Since I didn't find anywhere to put it, I thought I should add it in my application.properties under:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.output.producer.configuration
```

However, I couldn't compile the code using any the following formats:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.output.producer.configuration=request.timeout.ms=100000
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.output.producer.configuration={'request.timeout.ms':'100000'}
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.output.producer.configuration={"request.timeout.ms":"100000"}
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.output.producer.configuration=request.timeout.ms:100000
```

I'm always getting this error:

```
Binding to target org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaExtendedBindingProperties@104392ba failed:

    Property: spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings[output].producer.configuration
    Value: request.timeout.ms:100000
    Reason: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'bindings[output].producer.configuration'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'configuration': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Any idea how to implement this configuration to the producers?

Answer (score 1):

You should use in the following way :

`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.output.producer.configuration.request.timeout.ms=100000`

Configuration name should be followed by
 `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<binding name>.producer.configuration` prefix

In this way, you can add any number of configurations.

Comment: It doesn't work. Inteliij is painting it on red, and I see on debug mode the binding isn't happening...

Comment: Springboot 1.4.5, Kafka 0.10.2.1, Spring stream 1.3.0

Comment: I would recommend you to upgrade the versions, especially for Kafka 0.10. That's way too old. Apart from that, if you can show what error you get, it will be easy to help.

Comment: Boot 1.4 is very old too, and not supported - 1.5 goes out of support later this summer. IntelliJ needs metadata for auto completion; I am not sure when it was added, but it was recently broken (and fixed) in current versions. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1601